# How to capture an alien which has the ability to jump into a human's mind?

Tags: aliens

If an alien had the power to jump into a human's mind and control the human: how would it be possible to capture that kind of alien?

The alien is in the form a gaseous chemical life form. When inhaled by a human it can take control of the human's life after it reaches the human brain. It has the ability to come out of the human body at will by means of diffusing out of the human body at it wishes.

This alien is basically in gaseous form. So how to kill a alien which is just a gas compound?

Comment: Unless we're talking about indestructible-ish alien, such as the one in Alien movies, you would probably either vacuum it, or react it with some corrosive gas, like chlorine.

Comment: Do you want to capture or to kill the alien?

Comment: Hazmat suits and vacuums.

Comment: Obligatory XKCD: https://xkcd.com/1582/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Many ways I can think of :

- Vaccuum cleaner. Once he's trapped in a hermetic bag, you can do whatever you want with it.
- If it's flammable, flamethrower.
- If in space, open a breach in the ship, it'll be sucked out.

You can also go for extra dark solution where a possessed human sacrifice themselves to kill it, by jumping in an incinerator or something.

Comment: He could have a team running around with Minivac's and scuba gear so they can't breath it in...

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unclear; first you say *capture*, then *kill*. Assuming you mean the latter:

If this is not your first encounter with the alien, you should have time enough to analyze the gas(es) with a mass spectrometer, determine what chemicals (gases or liquids) react with it (or with one of the compounds, that should be enough) and use those to kill the alien.

Since is a gas life form is by definition very alien, you will be probably be able to find something that is not dangerous to humans.